# Unable to use created Sequelize model in Mocha tests

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, mocha.js

I am trying to use Mocha to test my Express routes, which involves creating and accessing the database using Sequelize. For example, if users are sending messages, I want to be able to mark the messages as read. Here is the start of one of these tests:

```
it('updates read/replied information on messages', async () => {
    after(() => {
      [DELETE CREATED MESSAGE]
    })
    before(() => {
      const sender = testUsers[1]
      const activeUser = testUsers[0]
  
      return Message.create({
        content: 'blahblah',
        sender_id: sender.id,
        receiver_id: activeUser.id,
      })  
    })

    const message = await Message.findAll()
```

But `message` is an empty array. I also tried defining `message` earlier with `let message`, and then assigning the model to that `message` variable, but it didn't work either. Earlier, I had used the technique:

```
describe('Routes', function () {
  let testUsers

  before(async () => {
    testUsers = await createAccounts(testData.users),
    return
  })
```

And I am able to access the `testUsers` models on all of my tests. But it seems I can't do the same for the `it` blocks.

What's a good way to be able to access newly-created models for these types of tests?

Comment: What's wrong with your second example? Defining the variables in outer scope seems good enough.

Comment: Yes, rewriting these tests is probably the best option. I thought maybe I was missing something simple.

Comment: By the way don't forget to await .creates as well. They are also async.